# Codegeneration with usings

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, code-generation

I´m using CodeDOM to build code from several xsd-files. So let´s assume we have some mapping from namespaces as defined in the xsd to those within the assemblies already created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abw="MyNamespace" xmlns:bfm="BaseNamespace" 
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="MyNamespace" 
        version="1.0.1.0">
  <import namespace="BaseNamespace" schemaLocation="Base.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>

  <element name="MyClass" substitutionGroup="bfm:MyBaseClass" type="abw:MyClassType"/>
  <complexType name="MyClassType">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="bfm:MyBaseClassType">
        <sequence>
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Property1" type="gml:ReferenceType">
            <annotation>
              <appinfo>
                <targetElement xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">abw:MyClass2</targetElement>
                <reversePropertyName xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">abw:MyClassAlias</reversePropertyName>
              </appinfo>
            </annotation>
          </element>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

Now - as the assemblies for the namespaces `BaseNamespace` and `gml` already exist - I want to build only the source-code for `MyClass` which should automatically reference the base-class `bfm:MyBaseClass` and `gml:ReferenceType` by adding a `using`-directive.

So I created a `CodeNamespace` for `targetNamespace` that applies the namespace `MyNamespace` from the xsd. Now I loop the types within that `CodeNamespace` and filter those that exist within my xsd as all the other types from the referenced xsd-files already *have* an assembly assigned to them. If a type was not defined in my xsd it should *not* be added to the code, however a `using` should be added.

```
var codeNamepscace = new CodeNamespace("targetNamepscae");
var tmp = code.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().ToArray();
foreach (var type in tmp)
{
    var typeFromSchema = schema.SchemaTypes.Names.Cast<XmlQualifiedName>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == type.Name);
    if (typeFromSchema == null)
    {
        string xsdNamespace = ???; // how to get the xsd-namespace for the current type here?
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found referenced type {0} which is not declared in current schema", type.Name));
        // omit the type from the current namespace and add a using-directive to the generated source-file if not yet done
        code.Types.Remove(type);
        // add a using-directive for the type if not already done
        if (!((IList)code.Imports).Contains(typeFromSchema.Namespace)) code.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(GetDotNetNSFromXsdNS(xsdNamespace)));
    }
}
```

The medthod `GetDotNetNSFromXsdNS` defines a mapping from the namespaces defined in the xsd-files to those within the assembly.

My question now is this: how do I get the namespace from within the xsd for a type within my `CodeNamepspace`? In particular: how can I exclude `gml:ReferenceType`  and `bfm:MyBaseClass` from generation and add them via `using`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works for me - although I consider it more a workaround:

```
var tmp = code.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().ToArray();     // temp. copy of our types-list to avoid ModifiedException during iteration
foreach (var type in tmp)
{
    var attributes = type.CustomAttributes.Cast<CodeAttributeDeclaration>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("System.Xml.Serialization"));
    var namespaceAttribute = attributes.SelectMany(x => x.Arguments.Cast<CodeAttributeArgument>()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Namespace");
    string xsdNamespace = ((CodePrimitiveExpression)namespaceAttribute.Value).Value as string;
    if (xsdNamespace != schema.TargetNamespace)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INFO: Found referenced type {0} which is not declared in current schema", type.Name);

        // omit the type from the current namespace and add a using-directive to the generated source-file if not yet done
        code.Types.Remove(type);

        var nameWithinAssembly = this.m_typeMapper.GetDotNetNamespaceFromXsdNamespace(xsdNamespace);
        // add a using-directive for the type if not already done
        if (!(code.Imports.Cast<CodeNamespaceImport>().Any(x => x.Namespace == nameWithinAssembly))) code.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(nameWithinAssembly));
    }
}
```

Here we assume that the namespace from the xsd is mirrored in the serialization-attributes. So we get the `CustomAttributes` for every type within ozur `CodeNameapace` and check if it has an `Namespace`-property defined on any of its attributes from `System.Xml.Serialization`. Finally all we have to do is to check if this namespace used for serialization is equal to the schemas target-namespace. If this condition doesn´t pass the type should be inferred using a `using`-directive which is done with the last line.